# How to add a link back to the application in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to add a few links to certain pages of the application in the ActiveAdmin pages. I can do this using sidebars, but I'll have to repeat the code for each of my resources. Is there anyway of adding custom links to the header ? Or define a sidebar that will appear for all resources ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I also wouldn't want to overlook setting config.site_title_link in initializers/active_admin.rb.

I'm pretty sure it takes a symbol representing the name of a route from your application, for example:

```
config.site_title_link = :root
```

would link the site title to your application's root_path.

Comment: Thanks! Was using an older version of ActiveAdmin that does not support a configurable title link. Upgraded to the latest version and configured it now.

Comment: And yes, it does support symbols as well

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you - obviously, if you need more than one link in your header, this doesn't accomplish that. But it seems like a very good start!

Answer (score 12):

Thanks @phoet ! Implemented it by overriding the HeaderRenderer instead:

```
  module ActiveAdmin
    module Views
      class HeaderRenderer
        def to_html
          title + global_navigation + application_link + utility_navigation
        end

        def application_link
          link_to('Back to Application', root_url)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Does this have to be put anywhere in particular? ex: `app/admin/views/header_renderer.rb`?

Comment: @mbillard: you can put it in any one of your files in the same directory where you define all your pages. This code will overwrite the methods in the internal ActiveAdmin classes.

Comment: Thats right, or a better place to put this would be in a separate file (maybe called active_admin_initializer.rb) under the config/initializers directory. All files under "config/initializers" directory will be loaded by Rails during startup.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on ActiveAdmin >= 0.5.0, this question has an answer that applies, but still isn't quite perfect. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620165/add-custom-items-at-header-menu-in-activeadmin

Answer (score 2):

i think there is no build-in way to do it, but you can override the render-logic in the TabsRenderer (2.2) / TabbedNavigation (3.0):

```
  def render_menu(menu)
    content_tag :ul, :id => @options[:id] do
      menu.items.collect do |item|
        render_item(item)
      end.join.<<('your_custom_stuff').html_safe
    end
  end
```