# Add custom items at header menu in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to add a link like link_to ("Edit yout profile", edit_user (current_user)) at header in ActiveAdmin.
Is that possible ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199753/how-to-add-a-link-back-to-the-application-in-activeadmin/7201824#7201824

Answer (score 18):

Recent versions of ActiveAdmin allow you to do this in your `active_admin.rb` initializer:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu do |menu|
    menu.add :label => 'Custom Menu' do |submenu|
      submenu.add :label => 'Custom Link', :url => custom_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12):

For recent versions of active admin, there are two solutions, both kind of unfortunate.

Any of your Resources with `menu false` can be set to `menu label: "Google", url: "http://www.google.com"`. This is unfortunate because it is highlighted as selected if you are on the resource from which you set it.

The other solution is to over-write the `ActiveAdmin::Views::Header` as above, but updated.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class Header < Component

      def build_global_navigation
        item = ActiveAdmin::MenuItem.new(label: "google", url: "http://www.google.com")
        @menu.add item
        insert_tag view_factory.global_navigation, @menu, :class => 'header-item'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This doesn't work exactly right, as you can't set things like `parent: "Developer"` for the menu item...
Anyway, I may make a fork so you can add items in the initializer to a particular namespace...Did anyone open an issue for this? I didn't see one.

Update:
I think this is the cleanest way to implement this (without contributing to active admin).

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Queue" do
  menu parent: "Developer", url: '/admin/resque'
end
```

Comment: There is an open issue for this https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1694

Comment: `@menu.add item` 
Will cause a new menu item to be added on each load of each resource (when you click on a resource at the top). 

`@menu.add item if @menu.items.select {|m| m.label == item.label}.blank?` 

Will check to see if a menu item with that label exists before adding it.

Comment: Another way, this is the easiest and cleanest I think:
`ActiveAdmin.register_page "Queue" { menu parent: "Developer", url:'/admin/resque' }`

Comment: The latter recommendation should definitely be the accepted solution on this!

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a later version of ActiveAdmin that has the capability for custom pages, you can do the following:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register_page "Store Admin" do
   controller do
     define_method(:index) do
       redirect_to "/store/admin"
     end
   end
 end
```

This overrides the `index` action of the PageController which normally just renders the page, but you can instead have it redirect to wherever you want to go, such as `edit_user_path`

Answer (score 0):

To me the @kristinalim answer almost work but his custom_path do not work, this give me a error. The next code work for me (I have to define the routes)

```
routes = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu do |menu|
        menu.add :label => 'Custom Menu' do |submenu|
            submenu.add label: 'Users', url: routes.admin_users_path
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this (for a number of years) has been to create an ***Action Item***; this is documented under *Custom Actions*:
https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html

Note that to get it to render as a *button* with the same styling as the built-in action buttons, the contents of the action item block should contain a hyperlink (even if it doesn't go anywhere). There may be other ways to do this but I haven't bothered to dig into the source code for it.

### Example

[image]

```rb
action_item :copy_parameters, only: :show do
  a(
    class:                 'clipboard-btn',
    'data-clipboard-text': JSON.pretty_generate(resource.parameters)
  ) { '  Copy parameters' }
end

action_item :go_to_some_path do
  link_to 'Go to the place!', admin_fun_stuff_path
end
```

Answer (score -2):

according to the post that @phoet mentioned, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7218598/445908) try this code:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class HeaderRenderer
      def to_html
        title + global_navigation + profile_link + utility_navigation
      end

      def profile_link
        link_to ("Edit yout profile", edit_user (current_user))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think this works as of 0.5.0 - please someone correct me if I am wrong.