# activeadmin utility_navigation dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Using ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre2 and Rails 4.2.1

I would like the default items in the utility_navigation area (right side of navigation bar) to be replaced with a drop down menu. This is so that I can continue to add actions to this menu related to the current login, without taking up additional space in the nav. bar.

I tried the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620165/add-custom-items-at-header-menu-in-activeadmin), as follows:

*config/initializers/active_admin.rb*

```
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
      menu.add label: "Test" do |submenu|
        submenu.add label: "ActiveAdmin.info", url: "http://www.activeadmin.info", html_options: { target: :blank }
        admin.add_current_user_to_menu  submenu
        admin.add_logout_button_to_menu submenu
       end #submenu
    end
  end
```

It works in principle, but the menu items are rendered outside the browser window,  see (cutoff menu image):

[image]

Can anyone provide a simple way to style the menu, to avoid this?  A trivial way to do this is to add more menu items to the right of the drop-down, but this defeats the desire to save space in the nav. bar.

Comment: did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is actual for current 1.1 version. A simple way to fix it temporarily with CSS only for dropdowns in the header. The code below will align dropdown always to left:

```
#titlebar_right {
  .dropdown_menu {
      position: relative;
  .dropdown_menu_list_wrapper {
      left: initial!important;
      top: 30px!important;
      right: 0px;
  }
  .dropdown_menu_nipple {
      left: inherit!important;
      right: 30px;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: sorry to take so long to get back. The titlebar_right applies to the "Holders" (wider pink title bar in my image).  The object I want to change is in the header (darker navigation bar that includes "dashboard"). I'm still trying to figure this out, I'm new at stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in version 2.9.0 of activeadmin.  Here is what fixed it for me:

```
#header {
  #utility_nav {
    .menu_item.has_nested {
      .menu_item {
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the style as @Troy was not enough for me:

```
#header {
  #utility_nav {
    .menu_item.has_nested {
      .menu {
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        width: unset;
        max-width: unset;
        right: 3px;
      }
      .menu_item {
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]